# Delete REG_MULTI_SZ - Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm trying to delete a REG_MULTI_SZ but receiving error that it is not there, even though I know it is

```
$reg = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager'
$regName = "PendingFileRenameOperations"

Remove-Item -path $reg\regName
```

Comment: You really shouldn't delete that subkey. It contains file rename operations or deletions that are scheduled when the system next boots.

Comment: I solved it myself. Should have used Remove-ItemProperty instead of Remove-Item. Bill - This key needs to be deleted in order to install a certain software and doesn't go away on next reboot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're mistaken about your assertion. You should not manually remove `PendingFileRenameOperations` as that registry value is managed by the system.

Comment: What happens if you delete it?

Comment: If you're not sure what it does, then you probably shouldn't meddle with it.

Comment: I thought you knew that is why I was asking.

Comment: My first reply tells what it does (actually I meant to write _value_ rather than _subkey_). But knowing its purpose doesn't change the fact that you shouldn't meddle with it.

Answer (score 1):

`PendingFileRenameOperations` is not a key, but a value, use `Remove-ItemProperty` instead:

```
Remove-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name $regName
```

But I have to concur with Bill_Stewart though, don't meddle with the Session Manager key